# Javascript:: Is audio.pause reset audio.currentTime value to 0?

Tags: javascript, function, audio, setinterval, addeventlistener

My code is working perfectly **except** the fact that instead of pause the track it's going back to the beginning of the track.

Here is my code:

```
var audio=new Audio();

var hezi=document.querySelector('#player>.button.hand');
var gangina=("textContent" in document)?"textContent":"innerText";

hezi.addEventListener
(
    'click',
    function()
    {

        if(audio.paused)
        {
            audio.src="Nadav Guedj - Golden Boy (Eurovision 2015 - Israel - Karaoke).mp3";
            hezi.innerHTML="&#9658;";
            audio.play();
        }
        else
        {
            hezi.innerHTML="||";
            audio.pause();
        }

    }
);
```

I'm going to assume that to solve this issue I need to store the `audio.currentTime` value of that track with `window.setInterval` and use the last `audio.currentTime` value to play the track from the last point where it stopped but I was wonder if there is continent way to make the pause/play button function properly (not to mention the fact that if I would store that last value via `window.setInterval` it wouldn't be 100% accurate since I'm relying on the interval value and not the exact specific point where the user paused the track).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is going back to the beginning because of this line,

```
        audio.src="Nadav Guedj - Golden Boy (Eurovision 2015 - Israel - Karaoke).mp3";
```

remove that, then audio.play would continue from where you paused. [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly9n7xqn/)

Comment: Yes I was figure that out by myself :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try to store in a variable the currentTime on the click event handler when user pauses the player.

This way you'll have the exact moment where the music was stopped, just store it on a variable out of object's scope.

Comment: So... in other words audio.pause DO reset the audio.currentTime value to 0 and this is the only solution to solve it (store the last value where it stopped) ?

Comment: Actually, I'm not familiar with audio's javascript API, but you can answer that question just checking currentTime values before and after calling audio.pause.

Comment: `audio.pause()` does not change the currentTime value. See @mido22's answer.